# How to find time difference between two cell in excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

"14/07/2016 09:26:59" & "14/07/2016 09:28:47" I could not find difference between this time. I have enter formula =A2-A1 result shows "#VALUE!" Please help me.

Comment: Have you formatted the cell that contains the cell as a date/time?  It sounds like it's still formatted for a general or decimal value.

Comment: yes i have formatted still showing error

Comment: Check format on other two cells as well, perhaps they are formatted with the wrong date/time order.  I'm not near my laptop at the moment so I can't play with it

Answer (score 1):

Your values are **text** rather than true date/times.  Once you converted the cells to date/times, you should see:

[image]

with the proper formatting for cell **A3**